# inicio de sesion emergente magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

How do I get the login form to pop up on the same page when I click on login?

In the image is graphically what I need to do. [image]

Answer (score 0):

In the default Magento theme, this feature is sot available. Either you can take help from a different Magento theme(which has a similar feature) or you need to extend your current theme using layout and template.
There is a popup login modal in checkout page. You can take help from that also.